# window.parent is not undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a single page. with no Iframes :

[image]

And I need to check if the page is in Iframe , so I did this :

`if  (!window.parent) {...not  in iframe...}`

But it seems that `window.parent` is never `undefined` and always reference to the window `(self===parent)`.

Why is that ?

the window has no(!) parent. so why it is defined ?

**NB**

- *I know that `window.window.w....` is the same for a reason. but im talking about parent(!)*
- *I know I can check this condition :*

`if (window.self===window.parent)...`

But still my question remains.

Comment: Interesting find. From Microsoft ref IE, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952669.aspx.  No explanation why though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.parent):

> If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference
>   to itself

That's just the way it is.

In their example, they provide a way of achieving your requirement (slightly different angle than your solution):

```
if (window.parent != window.top) {
  // we're deeper than one down
}
```

**More References:**

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/)

> The value of the parent attribute of a Window object MUST be the
>   parent document's Window object or the document's Window object if
>   there is no parent document

Comment: Agreed! And I would also love to know why, but I'm sure there's only a select few developers who know the real answer to that and it's unlikely they're frequenting here. If I had to *guess* at a reason behind it, the only logical one I can think of would be backwards compatibility from a time where this maybe made sense

Comment: I guess it could be the meaning (purpose) of parent that confuses then.  I am led to think "source" and so would expect undefined if the original window, but I guess it means something more like, eldest, where a self reference is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `document.referrer` with `window.location.href`

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/xnSNX/)</kbd>

Comment: No. document.referrer is not there to trust on.